# Namespacing theme CSS

Tags: css

What is the recommended way to namespace theme css in WordPress?

As fas as I know, there are two ways:

1. Namespace with the class, e.g.

   *.my-theme-namespace .alert {}*
2. Namespace with the prefix, e.g.

   *.mtn-alert*

Which one would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever works for you.

But a good practice is to start using a methodology like BEM.
http://getbem.com/

If you master BEM you'll find great pleasure in editing css files.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using BEM, but omitted it for brevity.